# PHP regex get specific line

Tags: php, regex

I'm not that good with regex and I tried multiple expressions but can't figure it out.

I have a big text file looking like this:

```
user1:asdffdf:asdasd
user2:asdafaf:adads
```

etc.

I need a regular expression for PHP that can match the username I want to get and return the line contents.

For example I want to get the line contents for "user2", but the regex should not match when searching for "adads" for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Your sample text doesn't really make it clear what you're wanting to match.

Comment: Space in front of username should be empty, then match the username and a colon behind it.

So if I need to find user2 the pattern would be:
"user2:"

And return the entire line.

Comment: Can you please edit your original question with examples on what should match and what shouldn't match?

Comment: `^` is the match anchor for start of line. Have you tried that? Please elaborate on your previous attempts otherwise. (Your question else currently just boils down to "gimme the regex".)

Comment: _but the regex should not match when searching for "adads" for example_ this isn't very clear at all. post two sets of examples, ones that should match, ones that should fail to match.

Comment: I don't seriously understand what is unclear. I have a variable $username = 'user2'; and I want to get the line that contains user2 as the first word before the first colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't seriously understand what is unclear. I have a variable
>   $username = 'user2'; and I want to get the line that contains user2 as
>   the first word before the first colon

```
$subject = 'user1:asdffdf:asdasd
user2:asdafaf:adads
user2:asdafaf:blah';
$username = 'user2';

if (preg_match_all('/^'.$username.':.*$/m',$subject,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print_r($matches);
}

//Array
//(
//    [0] => Array
//        (
//            [0] => user2:asdafaf:adads
//        )
//
//    [1] => Array
//        (
//            [0] => user2:asdafaf:blah
//        )
//
//)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match("/nothing in front/",$whereToSearchForMatches)){
        // do something

} else {
        // do something else 

}
```

Comment: Are you really wanting to look for "nothing in front" or the space in front to actually be empty?

Comment: Yeah I need the pattern not the function.